# why does ulimit -v not work under clang's address sanitizer?

Tags: c++, clang++, ulimit, address-sanitizer, libfuzzer

I'm using [libFuzzer](https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html) to fuzz an API.
The API is deserializing an array of bits (given by libFuzzer)
and converting them into c++ class instantiations.

Due to the serialization format, libFuzer is able construct a serialized object that tell the deserializer to reserve large amounts of data (which cannot be met).
This is done through calls to `std::vector::resize()`.  The vector throws a `std::bad_alloc`, and although the problem is caught and safely mitigated, it causes extreme lag in the fuzzer (as mentioned in the [following documentation](https://github.com/google/fuzzer-test-suite/blob/master/tutorial/libFuzzerTutorial.md#ooms) on OOM issues).

In an attempt to lower the amount of memory used when the fuzzer is running, I was hoping to set `ulimit -v` and adjust the available virtual memory of the process.  However doing so causes

```
==27609==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xdfff0001000 (15392894357504) bytes at address 2008fff7000 (errno: 12)
==27609==ReserveShadowMemoryRange failed while trying to map 0xdfff0001000 bytes. Perhaps you're using ulimit -v
```

**Why can't the address sanitizer work under ulmit -v?**
I wish it could, then I might be able to fuzz more effectively.

*Other information:*
My build flags were:

```
copts = [
    "-fsanitize=address,fuzzer",
    "-fsanitize-trap=undefined,integer",
    "-fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc,trace-cmp,trace-pc-guard",
    "-g",
    "-O0",
    "-fno-omit-frame-pointer",
    "-fno-sanitize=vptr",
],
linkopts = [
    "-fsanitize=address,fuzzer",
    "-fsanitize-trap=undefined,integer",
    "-fno-sanitize=vptr",
    "-fsanitize-link-c++-runtime",
],
```

I tried turning flags off so I could set `ulimit` and run the fuzzer:

```
copts = [
    "-fsanitize=fuzzer",
    "-g",
    "-O0",
    "-fno-omit-frame-pointer",
],
linkopts = [
    "-fsanitize=fuzzer",
],
```

but this causes an immediate segfault.

Comment: Is it possible to see `/proc/PID/maps` before crash? I wonder if shadow memory range is occupied by someone before Asan has chance to initialize and `mmap` it.

Comment: `ulimit` doesn't make you use less memory, it just prevents you from using more memory. What are you expecting to happen if the application wants more than the limit, if not an error?

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I was hoping that an artificial memory cap would cause the program to OOM more often, but reduce the latency lag.

Answer (score 2):

Asan reserves 1/8-th of process address space for shadow memory at startup to hold status of user data (allocated, freed, etc.). This is by design and there is nothing one can do about it.

Note that you generally don't care about virtual memory but rather physical one (which is also causing `new` to fail in your case).

Comment: Maybe he can modify his code to reduce the `ulimit -v` value after asan startup/initialization.